# intelliJ html class attribute autocomplete

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, intellij-idea, autocomplete, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working on a small web application which uses jQuery, Bootstrap and runs on spring boot with thymeleaf. The problem I am facing is that IntelliJ does not autocomplete html class attributes at all when using Thymeleaf, ctrl+space shows no suggestions:

[image]

I'm running IntelliJ idea Ultimate edition most recent version. All settings are set to default apart from minor theme changes. The project uses Gradle.

Is it something to do the way Thymeleaf looks for files on my project and can I configure my project so Thymeleaf would locate them for autocomplete? Or am I just missing something?

I found a quick hack, if you place the css file inside the same folder with the .html you're editing and include it using plain href="", the class autocomplete works. Though it will not work with Thymeleaf layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not missing anything. This is not implemented (yet), track [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132738) for more details.

Comment: Ah that's a shame, I guess we play the waiting game.